# Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?

> float conver = 45.**59**2346543;

I would like to round the actual value to one decimal place, conver = 45.**6**.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As Rob mentioned, you probably just want to *print* the float to 1 decimal place.  In this case, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  float conver = 45.592346543;
  printf("conver is %0.1f\n",conver);
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to actually round the stored value, that's a little more complicated.  For one, your one-decimal-place representation will rarely have an exact analog in floating-point.  If you just want to get as close as possible, something like this might do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  float conver = 45.592346543;
  printf("conver is %0.1f\n",conver);

  conver = conver*10.0f;
  conver = (conver > (floor(conver)+0.5f)) ? ceil(conver) : floor(conver);
  conver = conver/10.0f;

  //If you're using C99 or better, rather than ANSI C/C89/C90, the following will also work.
  //conver = roundf(conver*10.0f)/10.0f;

  printf("conver is now %f\n",conver);
  return 0;
}
```

I doubt this second example is what you're looking for, but I included it for completeness.  If you do require representing your numbers in this way internally, and not just on output, consider using a [fixed-point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) instead.

Comment: Rounds down seems to work OK but for example rounding 45.569346543; is 45.599998....or 45.5 with *1.0f....I'm closer thought, need to read floor and ceil again. thanks guys.

Comment: It is coming from floating point inaccuracy, I changed to double, works great. Thanks.

Comment: Just to reiterate Matt J's closing comment which I'm not sure you absorbed: 45.6 cannot be represented exactly in ANY binary floating point format, so that isn't what's being stored, even when you use double. If your program is now printing "45.6" it's because the output routines are rounding it for you.

Comment: `(conver >= (floor(conver)+0.5f)) ? ceil(conver) : floor(conver)` is equivalent to `floor(conver+0.5f)` (i think, you've meant exactly `>=`, not `>`).

Comment: Also it is better to do so: `conver>0f ? floor(conver+0.5f) : ceil(conver-0.5f)` — to work with negatives as well.

Answer (score 32):

Sure, you can use *roundf()*. If you want to round to one decimal, then you could do something like: `roundf(10 * x) / 10`

Comment: Nice, everyone else ignored the fact that the asker didn't ask to round to nearest integer. It should be noted that because of imprecision in floating point. When printing you will likely see "45.59999" given the example.

Comment: A nice more general solution would be: double f(double x, int decimal_points) { int n = pow(10, decimal_points); return roundf(n * x) / n; }

Comment: unresolved external symbol _roundf referenced in function _f  
have included math.h but it doesn't like roundf() I am in VS .NET, is foundf only for linux?

Comment: Tommy, roundf() is defined in C99, so every compliant compiler should support it. Perhaps you're not linking with the math library?

Comment: I don't think the newer visual studio's made any effort to support C99.

Comment: You could just use this though: floor((10 * x) + 0.5) / 10;

Comment: @EvanTeran you are right VS does not support C99 at all -only C89. M$ only seems interested in supporting C++, not C.

Comment: @EvanTeran `floor((10 * x) + 0.5) / 10;` fails for negatives number and for positive numbers where the sum of `(10 * x) + 0.5` itself rounds up before the `floor()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>

double round(double x);
float roundf(float x);
```

Don't forget to link with -lm. See also ceil(), floor() and trunc().

Comment: that round to the nearest integer...not what he asked for.

Comment: that's right, I got ahead of myself. I up voted Eduard's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to generalize Rob's answer a little, if you're *not* doing it on output, you can still use the same interface with `sprintf()`.

I think there is another way to do it, though. You can try `ceil()` and `floor()` to round up and down. A nice trick is to add 0.5, so anything over 0.5 rounds up but anything under it rounds down. `ceil()` and `floor()` only work on `double`s though.

EDIT: Also, for floats, you can use `truncf()` to truncate floats. The same +0.5 trick should work to do accurate rounding.

Comment: You can use `ceilf()` and `floorf()` and `roundf()` respectively for floats.

Comment: "A nice trick is to add 0.5," fails in many cases: [see comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own#comment57895810_497037).

Answer (score 1):

To *print* a rounded value, [@Matt J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497079/2410359) well answers the question.

```
float x = 45.592346543;
printf("%0.1f\n", x);  // 45.6
```

---

As most floating point (FP) is *binary* based, *exact* rounding to one *decimal* place is not possible when the mathematically correct answer is `x.1, x.2, ...`.

To convert the FP number to the *nearest* `0.1` is another matter.

**Overflow**: Approaches that first scale by 10 (or 100, 1000, etc) may overflow for large `x`.

```
float round_tenth1(float x) {
  x = x * 10.0f;
  ...
}
```

**Double rounding**: Adding 0.5f and then using `floorf(x*10.0f + 0.5f)/10.0` returns the wrong result when the intermediate sum `x*10.0f + 0.5f` rounds up to a new integer.

```
// Fails to round 838860.4375 correctly, comes up with 838860.5 
// 0.4499999880790710449 fails as it rounds to 0.5
float round_tenth2(float x) {
  if (x < 0.0) {
    return ceilf(x*10.0f + 0.5f)/10.0f;
  }
  return floorf(x*10.0f + 0.5f)/10.0f;
}
```

**Casting** to `int` has the obvious problem when `float x` is much greater than `INT_MAX`.

---

Using `roundf()` and family, available in `<math.h>` is the best approach.

```
float round_tenthA(float x) {
  double x10 = 10.0 * x;
  return (float) (round(x10)/10.0);
}
```

To avoid using `double`, simply test if the number needs rounding.

```
float round_tenthB(float x) {
  const float limit = 1.0/FLT_EPSILON;
  if (fabsf(x) < limit) {
    return roundf(x*10.0f)/10.0f;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use #define round(a) (int) (a+0.5) as macro
 so whenever you write round(1.6) it returns 2 and whenever you write round(1.3) it return 1.

Answer (score -1):

There is a `round()` function, also `fround()`, which will round to the nearest integer expressed as a double.  But that is not what you want.

I had the same problem and wrote this:

```
#include <math.h>

   double db_round(double value, int nsig)
/* ===============
**
** Rounds double <value> to <nsig> significant figures.  Always rounds
** away from zero, so -2.6 to 1 sig fig will become -3.0.
**
** <nsig> should be in the range 1 - 15
*/

{
    double     a, b;
    long long  i;
    int        neg = 0;


    if(!value) return value;

    if(value < 0.0)
    {
        value = -value;
        neg = 1;
    }

    i = nsig - log10(value);

    if(i) a = pow(10.0, (double)i);
    else  a = 1.0;

    b = value * a;
    i = b + 0.5;
    value = i / a;

    return neg ? -value : value;
}
```