# How to round off a double value to the next integer value in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, rounding

I know it's quite a silly question, but I really am finding the solution for the same. Suppose I am having a variable, `db1`, with a value 4.166667, and I want to convert it to an integer with the value 5. How should I do that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

int db1_int = (int)ceil(db1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round it using the `ceil` function found in math.h.

```
double notRounded = 4.1666667
int rounded = (int)ceil(notRounded);
```

Don't forget to `#include <math.h>`

Answer (score 0):

See Stack Overflow question *[Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018)*.

Objective-C works on top of C, so you can use this code.

Comment: I wanted to round it off to next integer value,so above function will be helpful.