# How Can I Round Type Float Variable WHEN PRINTED In C Language?

Tags: c++, c, variables, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own)

Before I cause any confusion...this is what I am using in C++

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
..
cout.precision(3);
..
```

I used that to round all PRINTED numbers to 3 decimal places in C++. I can't get that to work in C. Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own  This is a duplicate.  Please close.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf("%.3f", float_value);
```

where `.3f` indicates that you want precision 3.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Your code example implies `sprintf` not `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
printf("%0.3f", myFloat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with printf:

```
printf("%0.3f", n);
```