# Printing a float after rounding to 4 places

Tags: c

I have a rounding function,

```
float myround(float x, int places)
{
   float const shift = powf(10.0f, places);
   x *= shift;
   x = floorf(x + 0.5f);
   x /= shift;

   return x;
}
```

When I try to round of numbers to lets say 4 decimal places and then print the number with

```
printf("%f ", x);
```

I get the number without rounding. If I print it with

```
printf("%.4f ", x);
```

I get the number rounded to 4 places. Should the first printf not print the number to 4 decimal places as I have already rounded the number?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own)

Comment: `floorf(x + 0.5f)` sometimes does not return the nearest integer. `roundf(x)` would be better. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1

Comment: Here's an exercise: Try to write down 0.002 (base 10) as a base-2 (i.e. binary) floating point number with finite number of discrete digits. I save you the effort: You can't do it, 0.002 (base 10) can not be represented as a binary number with a finite amount of bits. By this single counterexample it should become clear, that you can't "round" every float to a finite number of base 10 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't round floats, you can only print them to a specific precision. All floats are always "unrounded", although you can obviously change the value to more closely approximate a rounded amount.

Answer (score 0):

From `man printf`

```
f, F   The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision
       specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal point  appears,  at  least one
       digit appears before it.

The fprintf(), printf(), sprintf(), vprintf(), vfprintf(), and vsprintf() functions conform to C89 and C99.
```

So, no, it should not do anything other than take 6 as the precision if you don't supply it.