# How do you round floats in C, using VisualDSP++?

Tags: c

Most C compilers offer some variation of the Standard C Library.  The VisualDSP++ compiler is no different.  However, I've recently encountered a scenario where I need to take a `float` value, round it to the nearest whole number and then convert it to an `int`.

This is rather easy using most variations of C, but after attempting to use `roundf`, I've found that `math.h` does not include the `roundf` function.

How can I correctly round my `float` variables to the nearest `int` value with VisualDSP++?

Comment: For those who are unaware of VisualDSP, it is an embedded systems development IDE an compiler.

Comment: Would the strategy in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/497079/7116) work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with VisualDSP, but you can round a float to an integer like so:

```
float number = 3.14;
int rounded = (int)(number + (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * 0.5);
```

So, you could write your own function for this:

```
int roundFloatToInt(float number)
{
    return (int)(number + (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * 0.5);
}
```

The above outputs the following for the given input:

`roundFloatToInt(0.10) --> 0`

`roundFloatToInt(3.14) --> 3`

`roundFloatToInt(3.54) --> 4`

It appears to work in all the cases I tested, including negatives.

Comment: I wouldn't name it `round`, since that's the name of a standard function in C99. Re-using the name could hurt the portability of the code.

Comment: And added support for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `*f()` functions, including `roundf`, were added in, as I recall, the 1999 version of the ISO C standard, along with the `roundd` function that operates on `long double`s.

It's <strike>likely</strike> possible that your `<math.h>` declares `round`, which operates on `double` rather than `float`. (C90 actually didn't have any of `round`, `roundf`, or `roundl`, but your implementation *might* provide `round` as an extension.) (EDIT: No, it doesn't.)

Untested code follows:

```
float x = 123.456;
int n = round(x);
```

`round` takes a `double` argument; the `float` argument passed to it will be implicitly converted. The `double` result is then implicitly converted to `int`.

You *could* make all the conversions explicit by adding casts:

```
int n = (int)round((double)x);
```

but that's just clutter.

EDIT: C89/C90 did define the `floor` and `ceil` functions. If `round` isn't available, it shouldn't be difficult to define it in terms of `floor`. The details depend on exactly what kind of rounding you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained my thoroughness a bit better.  I did a search throughout the entire VisualDSP++ application directory, which includes the include files and all internal C files.  "round" doesn't exist as a function name or as part of one within the entire compilers internal library.

Comment: Regarding your EDIT post.  There is a chance that this is a C89/90 compiler.  I inherited this project and since my primary background is Windows development, I'm use to the "conveniences" of more modern compilers that are kept up-to-date.  Visual C++ 6.0 is probably more  current that VisualDSP++.