# How to ensure that floating-point variables entered with 2 decimal places retain their exact value

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

Is there any way to ensure that a floating-point variable entered by the user, having 2 decimal places after the decimal point, retains its exact value, rather than losing precision?

This is the example case:
I want to round a `float` with 50 numbers after radix point, like this

> Before rounding = `0.70999997854232788085937500000000000000000000000000`

to this:

> After rounding = `0.71000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I became confused when I wanted to compare a `float` number in a condition like this:

> == Program Start== 
>   Input : 0.71

```
/* program logic */
if (input == 0.71) {
    printf("True !");     
} else {
    printf("False !");
}
```

> Output : **False !**
>   ==Program End==

The output was `False !` and will always be `False !` because the true value of user's input is `0.70999997854232788085937500000000000000000000000000`, and not `0.71000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Is there any way to round a `float` value like that? I read about the potential for inaccuracies with floating point here:

- [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)
- and followed it to these links: [Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own)
- and [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c#1344261)

However, these don't answer my question. If I use `ceilf(input * 100) / 100` function, it will make the input `0.71` into `0.71000` when `printf()`d using `%.5f` format - which seems to work. But when I print with `%.50f`, the real input value appears as `0.709999978542327880859375`. So, I can't compare to that value in my condition.

So, if floating point can never be accurate, what is the trick for the program logic above to get a `true` return value at that condition?

Comment: You can safely remove all of these trailing zeros from the question. they don't give anything except of cluttering the question.

Comment: Read about [Comparing Floating Point Numbers](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

Comment: A `float` value cannot even hold 50 decimal places: `double` can only hold about 16. Please [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c) - you mentioned this and other guaranteed duplicates, but omitted to explain why you are ignoring them, i.e. why you _think_ they don't solve this.

Comment: Anyway, floating point **is** always _accurate_ to specific extents; it just can't always be _precise_ for all numbers. These are well-defined concepts.

Comment: thank u @underscore_d for helping me edit my question, i was edit again my question about duplicate question as u told, please read :) , i'm sorry if i'm wrong with my statement about that duplicate question. I'm newbie in C :)

Comment: i need to read @JoachimPileborg suggested link, i interets with it, before i close this question or mark for one true answer here after i test it all.

Comment: @WilliamLuisan The point is that rather than worrying about tiny imprecisions in the _stored_ value, you just need to **compare** it in a proper, reliable way - which has been explained many times already, _ad nauseam_, in any half-decent discussion of floating-point representation. This is not a new question, by any means, and it _is_ answered by (many) duplicates. Also, you should probably use **`double`** variables, as they'll retain additional precision (albeit won't remove your obligation to use proper methods of comparison).

Answer (score 4):

All of the user's input comes in as *text*. The easiest -- and, possibly, safest -- way to check it is to compare it as a string before even converting to number:

```
if (strcmp("0.71", input) == 0) {
    printf("True !");
} else {
    printf("False !");
}
```

Of course, this may not be acceptable to you, if you wish to check for something other than equality :)

The other point is that you are interested in *fixed*, rather than floating numbers here -- but are confusing them with actual integers. If hundredths is what you'd like to work with, then work with the *integer numbers of hundredths*... For example, consider money -- instead of using `float` (or `double`) to store the amounts of *dollars* (like $7.61), use `int` (or, god bless you, `long`) to store *cents* (like ¢761).

Similarly, for another example, if you are counting time and need precision of one thousandth of a second, then use integer numbers of milliseconds, instead of floating-point number of seconds.

This will sidestep your entire problem altogether and may also make your programs faster...

Comment: Do you understand that such an approach is adding a *huge* performance overhead?

Comment: Actually, it is quite the opposite... Integers are usually faster than floats.

Comment: I mean the `strcmp` approach

Comment: He is talking about user-input, which came in as text. `strcmp` is much faster, than converting the text into a number was -- and then you still need to compare the result of the conversion with the number of your own.

Comment: i interest with this answer, i was looking about this, comparing float with another trick :D , but i have to test it, before i mark that your answer as the true answer :D (y)

Comment: @underscore_d, I'm hopeful, William was referring to the other part of my proposal -- where I suggested, he use _fixed_ variables to store and manipulate _fixed_-precision values. Even if the values aren't integer...

Comment: @MikhailT. Yeah, sorry, I was commenting based on having half-read it :/ deleted. Yours is a good idea overall, for units that lend themselves to discrete steps and so long as it's followed all the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can test equality with a range as you've experienced.
Just rewrite your equality test with:

```
if(input <= .71 + EPSILON && input >= .71 - EPSILON) {
}
```

Here you can create your own EPSILON based on your tolerance, or you can perhaps use FLT_EPSILON from `#include<cfloat>` for C++ or `#include <float.h>` in C.

Recall that floats do not have 50 digits of decimal precision. So trying to round at the 50th decimal place isn't going to work out so well. Floats have about 6 (sometimes more) digits of precision.

Comment: of course, in reality, one would factor such a test into a reusable function taking the compared value (and possibly a call-time epsilon, etc.)

Comment: Sure, that could be done. Here's a code snippet that should work: `int equal_floats(float first, float second, float EPSILON) { return first <= second+EPSILON && first >= second-EPSILON;}`  and then, this call would be `if(equal_floats(input,.71,0.0001))`  or something to that affect. Depending on your version, you might consider changing the int to bool as well in the function prototype.

Comment: That would be `#include <float.h>` as this is a **C** question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this question has been answered before, however:

```
float rounded_down = floorf(input * 100) / 100;   /* Result: 0.70 */
float nearest = roundf(input * 100) / 100;  /* Result: 0.71 */
float rounded_up = ceilf(input * 100) / 100; /* Result: 0.71 */
```

The library this functions belongs I think is math.h.

Comment: I'm sorry for my English too, I hope you understand. Anyhow the code I posted must do it for any case.

Comment: i was edit my question, please read again, i'm sorry if i'm wrong to prove that your answer from that Q&A thread doesn't fullfill my Question :)

Comment: This, on its own, does not provide an answer to the question since you haven't explained what you're supposed to do with it. Also, `. 70` and `. 71` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point, so `rounded_down` will actually be something like `. 699999988079071044921875`, and so on.