# how to convert float to close it number in (int)

Tags: c

```
float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
int i = index;
printf("%i",i);
```

1. //index equal 11.706415
2. //when I convert the index to int the int will equal 11 "I want it
   to be 12"

Comment: `int i = (int)roundf(index);`

Comment: `roundf` is in `math.h`.  You most likely have to link the library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own)

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code *rounds toward zero*, also known as *integer truncation*. You appear to what some form of *round to nearest*, but you didn't specify which.

---

In this particular case, you can use

```c
printf( "%.0f", index );
```

[By default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround), this *rounds to nearest, half to even*.

---

This *rounds to nearest, half away from zero*.

```c
#include <math.h>   // Also need to link math lib (e.g. using -lm)

int i = lroundf( index );
```

---

This *rounds to nearest, half up*.

```c
int i = index + 0.5;
```

---

| input | round to nearest half to even | round to nearest half away from zero | round to nearest half up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -7.5 | -8 | -8 | -7 |
| -6.5 | -6 | -7 | -6 |
| +6.5 | +6 | +7 | +7 |
| +7.5 | +8 | +8 | +8 |

Answer (score 0):

When you cast a `float` to an `int` it will be truncated.  You can use `roundf()` then cast the return value to an `int`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float index = 11.706415;
    printf("truncated: %d\n"
           "rounded:   %d\n",
           (int) index,
           (int) roundf(index));
}
```

Comment: Re "*Op didn't want a long they wanted an int.*" your comment doesn't make any sense. You're literally replying to me saying you can assign to a `long` to an `int` without cast (after you incorrectly claimed one was necessary), meaning they get an `int` as they wanted. I'm guessing you misread what I said??? Anyway, removed comments like I said I would, and I'll delete this one too.

Comment: You suggested changing %d to %ld which means you are printing a long.  To minimally change my code to use `roundl(index)` to print an int you need a cast.  You could also assign it to a variable but that is not what my code currently does (and there is no win over using `roundf())`.  I am very much open to feedback.  If the point is to print the value, and it probably is, then your answer is superior anyways.